# Camel load .xl3 files to jms

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms, hadoop2, camel-ftp

I am trying to send files from sftp server to jms topic using apache Camel. Camel fails to send `.xl3` files and load them to jms.

This is my route:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder()
{
    // @Override
    public void configure()
    {
        //from sftp to jms
        from("sftp://root@ip//usr/data?username=root&password=****&recursive=true&binary=true&idempotent=true").process(new Processor()

        {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
            {
                System.out.println("Sending file: "+exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));

            }
        }).marshal().string("UTF-8").to("jms:topic:JMSTopic");                                       
    }
});
```

Camel works fine with the other types of files (.txt, .csv, .xls...), but fails with .xl3.

Comment: camel doesn't differentiate between types of files. Check if you have permissions to read the file and folder

Comment: Camel process all type of files. Actualy, my camel program load .csv and .txt into jms, but fails with .xl3. In fact, camel uses a default converter to convert data to jms. I no know how to convert xl3 to load it into jms.

Comment: so the problem is not in gettinng files from ftp. But in sending that to jms. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, jms unable to read xl3 files.

Comment: do you get any exception?